# How do i iterate through JSON array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json data coming from rest in following format:

```
{
"status_code": 200, 
"data": {
"units": -1, 
"unit_reference_ts": null,
"tz_offset": -4,
"unit": "day", 
"countries": [{"country": "IN", "clicks": 12}]}, 
"status_txt": "OK"
}
```

I want to access the countries part and need to generate data in format like

```
{"IN":12, ......}
```

I dont know how to iterate through javascript, JSON array? Please help i am confused between methods which is the best & easiest that will work throughout the JSON?

I tried this:

```
 $.each(response.countries, function(key, value) {
 console.log(value.country + ": " + value.clicks);});
```

but it is showing me type error e is undefined...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Is it JSON, or is it an object, there's a difference ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript

Comment: its JSON data coming through url on request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you parse your JSON first (`var data = JSON.parse(json)`), then use a simple loop:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, l = data.data.countries.length; i < l; i++) {
    var tmp = data.data.countries[i];
    obj[tmp.country] = tmp.clicks
}

console.log(obj); // { IN: 12, UK: 123 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bo6ywbnf/)

Since (from your edit) you're using jQuery, you'll probably need to do this (note that jQuery automatically parses JSON data if you retrieve it using one of its AJAX methods):

```
var obj = {};
$.each(response.data.countries, function(key, value) {
    obj[value.country] = value.clicks;
});
```

If you want a string instead of an object, just `JSON.stringify` the obj:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bo6ywbnf/3/)